# Extract string using : as delimiter in shell

Tags: c, shell

I have a string

```
   "inet6 addr: 2620:cb:0:b007::23c3/112 Scope:Global",
```

and I want to extract only

```
  "2620:cb:0:b007::23c3"
```

from the above string.

How can I extract the substring using cut/sed/awk command.

Comment: Please post what you tried so far

Comment: Please remember the community is not a free-coding service! You have to let us know what you tried and failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am too new in shell but with cut command, it would be like:

```
   cut -f2-7 -d":" | cut -f1 -d "/"
```

Comment: I was able to understand easily

Answer (score 2):

Here is `awk` version: Using split function of awk.

```
 echo $x
"inet6 addr: 2620:cb:0:b007::23c3/112 Scope:Global",


echo $x |awk '{split($3,a,"/");print a[1]}'
2620:cb:0:b007::23c3
```

Or go with this:

```
echo $x |grep -Po '(?<=(: )).*(?=/)'
2620:cb:0:b007::23c3
```

OR Use `sed` to capture group of data  between `:` and first `/`. and then use backreference to print it.

```
echo $x |sed -r 's/^.*:( .*?)\/.*$/\1/'
2620:cb:0:b007::23c3
```

Or bash variable expansion:

```
echo ${x}
"inet6 addr: 2620:cb:0:b007::23c3/112 Scope:Global",
x="echo ${x%%/*}"
echo ${x##*addr: }
2620:cb:0:b007::23c3
```

Comment: I did not downvote this, but please refrain from answering such trivial stuff which could be easily solved by couple of simple look-ups and primarily don't when the author hasn't posted any of his research efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is using **awk**:

```
echo "inet6 addr: 2620:cb:0:b007::23c3/112 Scope:Global", | awk -F' |/' '{print $3}'
```